# Problem in returning methods from other method

Tags: python, flask

I have two methods which needs to be returned from another method. The problem is the method which returns the other methods is returning the method which comes first.

```
@app.route('/dashboard')
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
    return pending_registration()
    return registered_customers()
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

This is the method which returns the other methods. Here as `pending_registration()` is present at first so it's returning that also it is returning the `accept` and `reject` method but not the `registered_customers()`.

```
@app.route('/pending')
@is_logged_in
def pending_registration():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    result = cur.execute('SELECT * from registration')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    if result>0:
        return render_template('dashboard.html', users=data)
    else:
        msg = 'No Pending registration'
        return render_template('dashboard.html',msg=msg)
    cur.close()

# Registered Customers
@app.route('/registered')
@is_logged_in
def registered_customers():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    result = cur.execute('SELECT * from company_customers')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    if result>0:
        return render_template('dashboard.html', customers=data)
    else:
        msg = 'No customers'
        return render_template('dashboard.html',msg=msg)
    cur.close()
```

These are the 2 methods which are needed to be returned

Comment: The first return statement will return from this function and the other return statements will never be hit. You cannot return more than once from a function

Comment: so is there any way to make it happen cz the ```dashboard``` method needs values from all those methods so that it can load to the html

Comment: Why would you want your dashboard to be accepting and rejecting users when loaded? Just have links on the dashboard page to those views?

Comment: Yeah I corrected that mistake but what about ```registered_customers()```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the functions to be returned from `def dashboard()`, use:

```
def dashboard():
   return pending_registration(), registered_customers(), render_template('dashboard.html')
```

and you will get a tuple with the returned value of the three functions.

Comment: ```ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)``` getting this error

Comment: @BarefacedBear How are you calling the function `dashboard()` and where are you getting this error? It should be called like `a, b, c = dashboard()`, and if `render_template()` returns more than a single value, it should also be unpacked

Comment: I am calling the function ```dashboard()``` from the anchor tag href using ```{{url_for('dashboard')}}```

Comment: And for this ```a, b, c = dashboard()``` if I do it's showing this error ```RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.```

Comment: @BarefacedBear does running `return render_template('dashboard.html')` on itself from `def dashboard()` make sense? Commentize the first two rows in your `def dashboard()` (so it will be the only line running), and see if you get that error massage, and if so, it means you shouldn't have tried running that function as you did, and it's not just a problem of `return` order.

Comment: ```return render_template('dashboard.html')``` is returning the dashboard template on clicking an anchor tag present in another template that's why I had to return it in ```dashboard()``` function and after commenting 1st 2 rows no errors are showing...

Comment: Basically the ```pending_registration()``` & ```registered_customers()``` returns views upon clicking a button respectively. Both the buttons are present in same template ```dashboard.html```